# Growth of functions $~f~$, $~~f:\mathbb N~\to~\mathbb N~$.

Tags: inequality

True or false.

Suppose $~~f:\mathbb N~\to~\mathbb N ~-~\{0\}~$ and $~x < e^{f(x)}~$, for all $~x~$.

Let $~S=\{ x \in \mathbb N : f(x) < x \}~$.

Assume $~S~$ is infinite and let $~t >0~$.

Then there exists a real number $~c > 0~$ such that $~x < c~f(x)^{1+t}~$.

Answer (score 0):

Put $f(x)=\lceil \ln (x+2)\rceil$. Then $S$ is infinite, but for each $c,t>0$ there exists only finitely many $x$ such that $x<cf(x)^{1+t}$.